# HTML/Javascript login page not condisering login credentials when Javascript is disabled in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html/js login script. When the submit button is hit on providing the correct login details the homepage is opened. This works fine on Google Chrome and Firefox if Javascript is enabled. However when Javascript is disabled in Firefox the login credentials are not considered and the homepage is opened on hitting submit no matter what is typed in as username or password. Is there a way to disable the submit button in cases where Javascript has been disabled?
My script is:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- This is is the main start page saved in index.html -->
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>

<h2>Login details</h2>

<form name="login" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit()" action="http://localhost:8080/index.html" method="post">
<fieldset>
  <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
        function validateFormOnSubmit() {
        var un = document.login.username.value;
        var pw = document.login.password.value;
        var username = "username"
        var password = "password"
        if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
                return true;
        }
        else {
                alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
                return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: For example, instead of the 'submit' button, use button and assign it to send the form for the onclick event in js. Alternatively set in CSS to make the form invisible/inactive etc. And activate it using js.

Comment: Thanks Slawomir but how would you write this using the button properly and onclick?

Comment: Look here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp The form will only work if js is enabled. Just make sure there is additional validation of this data on the server? Validation with JS alone is a poor idea.

Comment: Especially entering password and user in js is an absurd idea.